# AS3: Starling+Nape test is too slow on iPhone (Github provided)

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, frame-rate, starling-framework

I've been starting to learn about Starling, then I found Nape. At GotoAndLearn.com I found a tutorial to use them both, and I did my own test with almost the same principles.

I've uploaded the project to github for a better understanding of the issue:

https://github.com/alesys/RolfNapeStarlingTest

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 (beta), exporting the sprite sheet from Flash Pro CS6, using the latest SWC for Starling and Nape, and the latest XCode.

I have 4 classes:

1. `RolfNapeTest` extends `flash.display.Sprite`. It's the main class.
2. `Assets`. It's used for embedding textures.
3. `Game` extends `starling.display.Sprite`. Handles all the Nape stuff.
4. `Char` extends `starling.display.Sprite`. Displays a random texture from `Assets` and listens for `starling.events.TouchEvent`.

So, one of the things I read is to make sure to embed the textures on a separated static class. So I did this with `Assets` class.

```
public static function getTexture(spriteName:String):Vector.<Texture>
        {
            if (!atlas)
                atlas = new TextureAtlas(Texture.fromBitmap(new SPRITES()),XML(new XMLSPRITES()));
            return atlas.getTextures(spriteName);
        }
```

`Char` class is also very simple:

```
package
{
    import nape.geom.Vec2;
    import nape.phys.Body;

    import starling.display.MovieClip;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import starling.events.TouchEvent;
    import starling.events.TouchPhase;

    public class Char extends Sprite
    {
        private var body:Body;
        public function Char(body:Body)
        {
            super();
            this.body = body;
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event):void
        {
            addChild(new MovieClip(Assets.getTexture((Math.random()>0.5)?Assets.SPRITE_FLAVIA:Assets.SPRITE_MARIANA)));
            pivotX = width>>1;
            pivotY = height>>1;

            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, handle_touch);
        }
        private function handle_touch(te:TouchEvent):void
        {
            if ( te.getTouch(this,TouchPhase.BEGAN))
            {
                body.velocity = new Vec2(Math.random()*1000-500,-2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It receives a `Body` instance as a param, loads a texture, listen for a `touch` event and when it happens changes `Body`'s velocity.

Now, the class that handles Nape is `Game`:

```
package
{
    import nape.geom.Vec2;
    import nape.phys.Body;
    import nape.phys.BodyType;
    import nape.phys.Material;
    import nape.shape.Polygon;
    import nape.space.Space;

    import starling.display.DisplayObject;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {
        private var space:Space;
        private var count:int;
        public function Game()
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        private function init(e:Event):void
        {
            space = new Space(new Vec2(0,3000));

            var walls:Body = new Body(BodyType.STATIC);

            var wall_left:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.rect(-20,0,20,stage.stageHeight));
            var wall_right:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.rect(stage.stageWidth,0,20,stage.stageHeight));
            var floor:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.rect(0,stage.stageHeight,stage.stageWidth,20));

            walls.shapes.add(wall_left);
            walls.shapes.add(wall_right);
            walls.shapes.add(floor);

            walls.space = space;
            count = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            if ( Math.random()<0.03 && count < 50)
            {
                count++;
                addChar();
            }
            space.step(1/60);
        }

        private function addChar():void
        {

            var body:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC,new Vec2(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth,-200));
            body.shapes.add(new Polygon(Polygon.box(50,100),new Material(20)));
            body.graphic = new Char(body);
            body.graphicUpdate = graphicUpdate;
            body.space = space;
            addChild(body.graphic);
        }

        private function graphicUpdate(body:Body):void
        {

            var gra:DisplayObject = body.graphic as DisplayObject;
            gra.x = body.position.x;
            gra.y = body.position.y;
            gra.rotation = body.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is very straight. Creates a `Space` instance, then creates some walls and finally listens for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` to call `Space.step()` and to randomly create new `Char` instances.

Now I understand that probably I should have created all 50 instances of `Char` class and `Object` pool them. But also I understand this only affects the performance at instantiation time. But probably that will be the first thing I will modify in the next commit.

So, tested it on Browser and Air, it works just fine. Never drops from 60fps as expected.

Then I tried it on my iPhone4S. Everything goes smooth at 60fps until I reach around 30 instances. Then it starts to drop very hard until it reaches 30fps.

Also I have to add this: for some reason I'm having a lot of warnings from Nape SWC:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The definition getClass.T depended on by Type in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition getClass.T depended on by Type in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by flash.Boot in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by flash.Boot in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.CbTypeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.CbTypeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.Listener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.Listener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.ListenerList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.ListenerList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.PreListener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.callbacks.PreListener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.constraint.Constraint in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.constraint.Constraint in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.constraint.ConstraintList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.constraint.ConstraintList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.ArbiterList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.ArbiterList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.ContactList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.ContactList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.InteractionGroupList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.dynamics.InteractionGroupList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.GeomPoly in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.GeomPoly in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.GeomPolyList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.GeomPolyList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.RayResultList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.RayResultList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.Vec2List in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.geom.Vec2List in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.BodyList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.BodyList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.CompoundList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.CompoundList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.InteractorList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.phys.InteractorList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.shape.EdgeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.shape.EdgeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.shape.ShapeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.shape.ShapeList in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.space.Space in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by nape.space.Space in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by StringTools in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by StringTools in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_Callback in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_Callback in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_InteractionListener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_InteractionListener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_Listener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_Listener in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_OptionType in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.callbacks.ZPP_OptionType in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_AABB in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_AABB in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Collide in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Collide in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_GeomPoly in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_GeomPoly in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_GeomVert in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_GeomVert in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Mat23 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Mat23 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Ray in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Ray in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Vec2 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Vec2 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Vec3 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.geom.ZPP_Vec3 in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.phys.ZPP_Compound in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.phys.ZPP_Compound in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.phys.ZPP_Interactor in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.phys.ZPP_Interactor in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.shape.ZPP_Polygon in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.shape.ZPP_Polygon in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_DynAABBPhase in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_DynAABBPhase in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_Space in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_Space in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_SweepPhase in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.space.ZPP_SweepPhase in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Debug in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Debug in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_MixVec2List in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_MixVec2List in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_Body in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_Body in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found  RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_CbSet in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_CbSet in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_CbSetPair in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_CbSetPair in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_PartitionVertex in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_PartitionVertex in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleEvent in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleEvent in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found   RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleSeg in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleSeg in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleVert in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    NapeTest2       line 0  Flex Problem
The definition Null.T depended on by zpp_nape.util.ZPP_Set_ZPP_SimpleVert in the SWC /Users/rolf/Documents/AS3 libs/Nape/swc/release_nape.swc could not be found    RolfNapeTest        line 0  Flex Problem
```

So, the question is: Aside of `Object` pooling all the `Char` instances, am I missing something else that may be causing this FPS drop? maybe all these Warning messages from SWC have something to do with this but why this doesn't happen on Air or Browser?

Or should I simply switch to Box2DFlashAS3?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well I think the warnings are probably unrelated, the performance on the iPhone is just going to be worse because it's a slower processor and has less RAM than your computer, so I don't find that really surprising.  In terms of what is wrong, I don't see anything obvious in your code that should really burn a lot of performance, though coming up with a different method for randomizing the addition of characters like varying a timer's delay would be better than a condition that most of the time evaluates to false.  Aside from that  I would just comment out pieces until you can see what does it.

Comment: Yes, maybe I overestimated the performance on iOS since everybody has been really excited about the new compiler, stage 3d performance on iOS, etc.  

I'm going to object pool all the instances, do a timer (as you recommend) to insert the sprites, check how it perform, then try Box2D and compare the performance.

Comment: The errors your getting on the swc part appear to be related to haxe files that are part of the Nape source but if everything is compiling and running I'm just guessing that it doesn't matter that they're missing in this case as I haven't used Nape or developed Flex for iOS.  Do you have a separate project that is meant to build the nape swc that is causing those errors or are those showing up when you try to compile your app (they appear to be compile time errors rather than warnings in which case it wouldn't produce the swf/swc)

Comment: Well, I used Object pool and changed the spawn to a fixed timer. But the speed was still dropping to 30fps. Then decreased the number of objects on screen from 50 to 25 and it's doing 60fps without any problem. So at this point I'm still a little clueless of what I could have done to allow 50 objects on stage. The update is already on gitHub

Comment: At the end of the day, exporting as a Release Build allow it to display 50 objects at 60fps. Newbie mistake, it was my bad :P

Comment: Ah well good to know and glad you figured it out.